# Reallocation of shared memory in c

Tags: c, shared-memory, realloc

could we reallocated a shared memory ? by passing it's address to `realloc` function , if NO , how I can reallocate the shared memory ?

Comment: Please tell us what kind of shared memory. What function did you call to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`mremap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mremap). Alternatively, you can call [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) again, copy the data, and [`munmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap) the original.

Comment: are you sure that it will resize a shared memory  , i always return Error !

Comment: It will if it can. The pointer you pass in for the old address needs to be one that was returned by a previous call to `mmap()` or `mremap()`.

Comment: ...wait, what `mmap()`? What about shmget() and shmat()?

Comment: @SF.: I prefer not to use the SysV interfaces unless I am forced to do so, and I preach what I practice. However, probably after a `shmget()` of the new area, you would `shmat()` it someplace and copy what you needed copied, then `shmdt()` the original. There is no `mremap()` equivalent.